# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' -- Dart/Flutter Error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I have an API set up that returns the following output on a specific endpoint when called:

```
{
    "total_user_currency": 0.1652169792,
    "total_sats": 2184,
    "total_btc": 0.00002184,
    "outputArray": [
        {
            "txid": "642fd534cb3a670a31f4d59e70452b133b0b461d871db44fcc91d32bb6b6f0cc",
            "vout": 2,
            "status": {
                "confirmed": true,
                "block_height": 625673,
                "block_hash": "0000000000000000000310649c075b9e2fed9b10df2b9f0831efc4291abcb7fb",
                "block_time": 1586732907
            },
            "value": 546
        },

    ]
}
```

And I'm using the following dart class to decode that JSON into an Object that I can interact with:

```
class UtxoData {
  final dynamic totalUserCurrency;
  final int satoshiBalance;
  final dynamic bitcoinBalance;
  List<UtxoObject> unspentOutputArray;

  UtxoData({this.totalUserCurrency, this.satoshiBalance, this.bitcoinBalance, this.unspentOutputArray});

  factory UtxoData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var outputList = json['outputArray'] as List;
    List<UtxoObject> utxoList = outputList.map((output) => UtxoObject.fromJson(output)).toList(); 

    return UtxoData(
      totalUserCurrency: json['total_user_currency'],
      satoshiBalance: json['total_sats'],
      bitcoinBalance: json['total_btc'],
      unspentOutputArray: utxoList
    );
  }
}

class UtxoObject {
  final String txid;
  final int vout;
  final Status status;
  final int value;

  UtxoObject({this.txid, this.vout, this.status, this.value});

  factory UtxoObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UtxoObject(
      txid: json['txid'],
      vout: json['vout'],
      status: Status.fromJson(json['status']),
      value: json['value']
    );
  }
}

class Status {
  final bool confirmed;
  final String blockHash;
  final int blockHeight;
  final int blockTime;

  Status({this.confirmed, this.blockHash, this.blockHeight, this.blockTime});

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Status(
      confirmed: json['confirmed'],
      blockHash: json['block_hash'],
      blockHeight: json['block_height'],
      blockTime: json['block_time']
    );
  }

}
```

Here is the function that actually calls the API in the code:

```
Future<UtxoData> fetchUtxoData() async {
    final requestBody = {
      "currency": "USD",
      "receivingAddresses": ["bc1q5jf6r77vhdd4t54xmzgls823g80pz9d9k73d2r"],
      "internalAndChangeAddressArray": ["bc1q5jf6r77vhdd4t54xmzgls823g80pz9d9k73d2r"]
    };

    final response = await http.post('https://thisisanexmapleapiurl.com', body: jsonEncode(requestBody), headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} );

    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      notifyListeners();
      print(response.body);
      return UtxoData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Something happened: ' + response.statusCode.toString() + response.body );
    }
  }
```

However, when I do run the function, I get the following error in my editor:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double')
```

I get it on the return UtxoData statement inside the factory method for the UtxoData class as shown below:

```
return UtxoData(
      totalUserCurrency: json['total_user_currency'],
      satoshiBalance: json['total_sats'],                    <<<<============= The exception pops up right there for some reason
      bitcoinBalance: json['total_btc'],
      unspentOutputArray: utxoList
    );
```

This is strange because I know that the API is returning an int there. totalUserCurrency and bitcoinBalance have to be dynamic because they can either be 0 (an int) or an arbitrary number like 12942.3232 (a double).

Why do I get this error and how can I correct this? Much appreciated

Comment: I put it in variable j except for the "," at the end of your json.
I replaced UtxoData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); with UtxoData.fromJson(json.decode(j)); and it worked.
Isn't it possible to get a double value instead of an int?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. I thought so as well. Do you mind sharing a gist or pastebin of the code you tried that worked?

Comment: Of course. Also, please show the response data at that time in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd a similar problem where the amount I was getting from an API veried between 0 and few thousands including decimals. I tried the following :

```
this.balanceAmount = double.parse(json['total_balance']??'0.0'.toString());
```

This didn't work with my dataset. So, I enhanced it to the following which worked in all the cases for my dataset. You might need slight enhacement(s).

```
double parseAmount(dynamic dAmount){

    double returnAmount = 0.00;
    String strAmount;

    try {

      if (dAmount == null || dAmount == 0) return 0.0;

      strAmount = dAmount.toString();

      if (strAmount.contains('.')) {
        returnAmount = double.parse(strAmount);
      }  // Didn't need else since the input was either 0, an integer or a double
    } catch (e) {
      return 0.000;
    }

    return returnAmount;
  }
```

Comment: If you follow that logic, when you receive an integer, you are returning 0.00. I don't see the difference with the parse method and the optional onError property

Comment: That's right. It is because, in my case, A. the constructor needed a double but B. the server was automatically rounding say 2122.0 to 2122. It was creating a problem. I think it was made in Php and that's probably how Php work. And that's the reason, I'd specific condition of contains('.')

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing data, and you are unsure if it will be an `Int` or a `double` there are multiple solutions.

If you need an `Int` use `parsedData.truncate()` this works for both `Int` and `double` and it resolves into an `Int` by discarding decimals. Similarly you could also use `cail()` or `floor()` if you want the decimals to have some effect in the outcome.

So, in your case, you would only need to do like this:

```
satoshiBalance: json['total_sats'].truncate(),
```

I hope this helps!